# Less than or Equal Condition Android

Tags: java, android, listview, conditional-statements

I have one quote application which has a "Load more" button visible only if the quote list size is 15. Now I want change the condition so that it must show the button only if the quote list size is more than 15. My current code is like below and I have tried to change it to:

```
if(c.getCount()<=15){
    // Not Showing Load More Button     
}
```

but it's not showing my button.

My code for that button is below:

```
final Button btnLoadMore=new Button(this);
            btnLoadMore.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#351802"));
            btnLoadMore.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e8d8a7"));
            btnLoadMore.setTypeface(btnLoadMore.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            btnLoadMore.setText("Load More Quotes");


            if(c.getCount()<15){
                // Not Showing Load More Button

            }

            else {

            list.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);}
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            anifadein=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slidedown);
            list.startAnimation(anifadein);

            // Click event for single list row
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    map = quotesList.get(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuotesActivity.this,
                            QuoteDialogActivity.class);
                    int itemPosition     = position;
                    if(startingPoint>=30){


                        intent.putExtra("Pos", itemPosition+1);
                        intent.putExtra("LstCount", list.getCount()-1);
                    }else{
                        intent.putExtra("Pos", itemPosition+1);
                        intent.putExtra("LstCount", list.getCount());}
                    intent.putExtra("QuoteId", map.get(KEY_ID));
                    intent.putExtra("quotesType", quType);
                    intent.putExtra("startFrom", getIntent().getStringExtra("startFrom"));
                    intent.putExtra("Quotes", quotesList);
            //  Log.i("COUNT",""+(itemPosition+1)+"-"+list.getCount());
                    intent.putExtra("Fav", map.get(KEY_FAVORITE));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitial.show();
                    }

                }
            });

             btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        if(btnLoadMore.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                        Cursor newC = null;

                        if (quType != 0) {

                            switch (quType) {
                            case 1:


                                    newC = db.getQuotes(""+startingPoint);


                                break;
                            case 2:
                                newC = db.getFavoriteQuotes(""+startingPoint);
                                //page.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                newC = db.getAuthorQuotes(getIntent().getStringExtra("AuthorId"),""+startingPoint);
                            //  page.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        // Starting a new async task
                        if(newC.getCount()<15){
                            btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }
                        startingPoint+=15;  
                        do{
                            map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value
                            map.put(KEY_ID, newC.getString(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                            map.put(KEY_TEXT, newC.getString(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT)));
                            map.put(KEY_AUTHOR, newC.getString(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_AUTHOR)));
                            map.put(KEY_PICTURE, newC.getString(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_PICTURE)));
                            map.put(KEY_PICTURE_SDCARD, String.valueOf(newC.getInt(newC
                                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_PICTURE_SDCARD))));
                            map.put(KEY_WEB_ID,
                                    String.valueOf(newC.getInt(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB_ID))));
                            //Log.i("web_id",String.valueOf(newC.getInt(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
                            map.put(KEY_FAVORITE, newC.getString(newC.getColumnIndex(KEY_FAVORITE)));

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            quotesList.add(map);
                            if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                                mInterstitial.show();
                            }

                        } while (newC.moveToNext());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  }}
                });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I not sure from where Object "c" is coming but i m assuming it list object and getCount is return the current count of list. So, If you want to show "Show more" button when the size of list is greater than or equals to 15 then use this condition.

```
if(c.getCount() >= 15){
    // Will show Load More Button     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the Button in a layout XML File. Inflate it, then:

```
if (c.getCount() > 15) {
    btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

If you want the `Button` to be invisible.